# Add a variable into a regex

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a little problem of comprehension with my regex
I just want add a variable inside my regex

I've got this:

```
static test(Prefix, version: string) {
    return "/^" + Prefix + "[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*-[0-9]*-(SNAPSHOT)$/.test(version);
} 
// I don't understand where to put my last "
```

thanks for your help

Comment: What example strings would you like this regex to match?

Comment: return "/^" + Prefix + "[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*-[0-9]*-(SNAPSHOT)$/.test(" + version + ")"; you mean something like this? I don't get the question exactly

Comment: for example: base-1.0.0-1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Dropping unknown strings in the middle of a `regex` can produce unexpected or even invalid regular expressions. For example, if `Prefix` is `'.'` (you want the match the strings that start with a dot), the `regex` generated this way starts with `^.[0-9]*...` and matches strings no matter how they start (because in `regex` a dot matches any character). Similar for other characters that are special in `regex`.

Comment: `return new RegExp("^" + Prefix + "[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*-[0-9]*-(SNAPSHOT)$").test(version);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a regexp expression via [`new RegExp(string)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Comment: You can also add a link to docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp